# sum values in a child entity

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I have an entity with a parent class and two child classes, like this:

Tax Report --> Parcel --> Tax Collector

Tax Report contains a collection of Parcel, and Parcel contains a collection of Tax Collector.

My Tax Report object has 2 Parcel objects associated with it, and each Parcel object has 2 Tax Collector objects associated with it. The Tax Collector object has a property called Taxes Due that I am interested in. Here is an example of the data:

TaxReport: 1

Parcel: 0001
      Tax Collector: Dallas County, $100 in taxes due
      Tax Collector: Collin County, $50 in taxes due

Parcel: 0002
      Tax Collector: Collin County, $1000 in taxes due
      Tax Collector: City of Irving, $100 in taxes due

I want to query my objects to sum the taxes due for all parcels, grouped by Tax Collector. Here is what I want my result to look like:

Dallas County, $100
Collin County, $1050
City of Irving, $100

I have tried something along these lines:
var taxsummary = from tr in taxreport.Parcel.Select(y=>y.TaxCollector).Select(n=>n.TaxesDue).Sum()

But I haven't had any luck. My results are always projected as a multi-level collection with Taxes Due below each Parcel, not grouped by Tax Collector. Any ideas?

Thanks,
Brad

Comment: Had to delete my first approach. Will write something more intellegent in a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does the trick:

```
var grouped = from parcel in taxReport.Parcels
              from taxCollector in parcel.TaxCollectors
              group taxCollector by new 
              {
                  Name = taxCollector.Name // Or whatever makes it Unique...
              };

foreach(var collectorGroup in grouped)
{
    Console.WriteLine(collectorGroup.Key.Name + " : " + collectorGroup .Sum(p => p.TaxesDue));
}
```

If you want something like a Dictionary you can do this:

```
var grouped = (from parcel in taxReport.Parcels
               from taxCollector in parcel.TaxCollectors
               group taxCollector by new 
               {
                   Name = taxCollector.Name
               } 
               into groupedCollectors
               select new 
               { 
                   Name = groupedCollectors.Key.Name, 
                   TaxesDue = groupedCollectors.Sum(p => p.TaxesDue)
               }) 
               .ToDictionary(p =>p.Name, p => p.TaxesDue);
```

Comment: Perfect! Works like a charm! I've been beating my head on the table for two days. I don't understand what the .ToDictionary() does, but it works! Your 2nd solution is exactly what I needed. Thanks again!

Comment: the ToDictionary requires two Parameters. The first is the Function that returns the keys, the second gives us the values.
I dont know how it works intenally, but i bellieve it iterates thorugh all items, then executes the first lambda for the key, then the second for the value.

It basically mapps every Item from the Query, by taking every Items Key and Every Items TaxesDue.

Comment: it's giving me the results I want without the .ToDictionary() portion, so I think I'll leave that part off and map to the groupedCollectors